# What should I name variables for buttons which has specific roles

Tags: naming-conventions

In general, we should name functions in order to follow starting with verbs, and name variables in order to follow starting with nouns. But if the target object has a specific role such as a button to create something and I want to define variables related to it, I've named it like "createButtonStyles". Especially, on programming languages which have functions as first-class objects such as JavaScript, it's hard to guess a role when we read their names. For example, when we read `createButtonStyles`, we have to guess whether the variable has styles of a button or the variable is to create styles button.

```js
const createButtonStyles = { color: "red" }; // Styles for a create button
function createButtonStyles { ... }; // A function to create styles of create button
```

What should I name them?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can name your variable `stylesForCreateBtns` or if you have mutltiple button-style variables name them with some sort of prefix like `buttonStyles~`, so it will start with noun: `butonStylesCreateBtn`, `buttonStylesDeleteBtn`, `buttonStylesNextBtn`. Plus it will in an autocomplete tool like IntelliSense sort them next to each other.